# Replace string patterns recursively in java

Tags: java

I have a utility class to resolve a string input with certain patterns as shown in the example below. All variables are surrounded by `{` and `}`. If my string is something like `Language is {lang} and version 2 is {version}. Home located at {java.home}` the output is `Language is java and version 2 is 1.8. Home located at C:/java` and if my string is like `Language is {lang} and version 2 is {version}. Home located at {{lang}.home}` the output is `Language is java and version 2 is 1.8. Home located at {java.home}`. All I am trying to find is a way to resolve nested properties recursively but ran into several issues. Can any logic be inserted into the code so that resolving of inner properties happen dynamically?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class MyClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {
   System.setProperty("lang" , "java");
   System.setProperty("version" , "1.8");
   System.setProperty("java.home" , "C:/java");
   System.out.println(resolve("Language is {lang} and version 2 is {version}. Home located at {java.home}"));
   System.out.println(resolve("Language is {lang} and version 2 is {version}. Home located at {{lang}.home}"));
}
public static String resolve(String input) {
    List<String> tokens = matchers("[{]\\S+[}]", input);
    String value;
    for(String token : tokens) {
        value = getProperty(token);
        if (null != value) {
            input = input.replace(token, value);
        }
        value = "";
    }
    return input;
} 

private static String getProperty(String key) {
   key = key.substring(1, key.length()-1);
   return System.getProperty(key);
}

public static List<String> matchers(String regex, String text) {
    List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        matches.add(matcher.group());
    }
    return matches;
}

public static boolean contains(String regex, String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
    return matcher.find();
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to ask for the pattern to get only the value without an inner `{` or `}` with `[^{}]`. No "curly bracket"  means no inner values. So you can safely do the replace.

First, we create a `Pattern`, we need to escape those `{}`... and we add a capture group for later.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^{}]+)\\}");
```

Then we check with the current value:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
```

Now, we just have to check if there is a match and loop on it.

```
while( m.find() ){
    ...
}
```

In there, we will need the value captured, so we get the first group and get its value (let assume it will always be present) :

```
String key = m.group(1);
String value = properties.get(key); //add some fail safe.
```

Using the `Matcher.replaceFirst`, we will safely replace only the current match (the one we get the value from). If you use `replaceAll`, it will replace every pattern with the same value.

```
s = m.replaceFirst(properties.get(key));
```

Now, since we have updated the `String`, we need to call check the regex again :

```
m = p.matcher(s);
```

Here is a full example:

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
properties.put("lang", "java");
properties.put("java.version", "1.8");

String s = "This is {{lang}.version}.";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{([^{}]+)\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find()){
    String key = m.group(1);
    s = m.replaceFirst(properties.get(key));
    System.out.println(s);
    m = p.matcher(s); //Reset the matcher
}
```

> This is {java.version}.
>
> This is 1.8.

---

This has one problem, it will required to a lot of Matcher initialisation, so it might not be optimal. Of course, it is most likely not optimized (not the point here)

---

FYI : Using the `Matcher.replaceFirst` instead of the `String.replaceFirst` prevent a new `Pattern` compilation to be done. Here is the `String.replaceFirst` code :

```
public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement) {
    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(this).replaceFirst(replacement);
}
```

We already have a `Matcher` to do that, so use it.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways you could achieve this.

You need some way to communicate to the caller either whether a replacement is necessary, or whether one was made.

A simple option:

```
public boolean hasPlaceholder(String s) {
    // return true if s contains a {} placeholder, else false
}
```

Using this you can repeatedly replace until done:

```
while(hasPlaceholder(s)) {
    s = replacePlaceholders(s);
}
```

This does scan through the string more times than is strictly necessary, but you shouldn't optimise prematurely.

---

A more sophisticated option is for the `replacePlaceholders()` method to report back whether it succeeded. For that you'll need a response class that wraps the result String and the `wasReplaced()` boolean:

```
ReplacementResult replacePlaceholders(String s) {
     // process string into newString, counting placeholders replaced
     return new ReplacementResult(count > 0, newString);
}
```

(Implementation of `ReplacementResult` left as an exercise)

Using this you can do:

```
ReplacementResult result = replacePlaceholders(s);
while(result.wasReplaced()) {
   result = replacePlaceholders(result.string());
}
```

So, each time you call `replacePlaceholders()` it will *either* make at least one replacement, or it will report false having verified that there are no more replacements to make.

---

You mention recursion in the question. This can of course be done, and it would mean avoiding scanning through the whole string each time -- as you can look at just the replacement fragment. This is untested Java-like pseudocode:

```
String replaceRecursively(String s) {
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    while(Token token = takeTokenFrom(s)) {
        if(token.isPlaceholder()) {
            String rawReplacement = lookupReplacement(token);
            String processedReplacement = replaceRecursively(rawReplacement);
            result.append(processedReplacement);
        } else {
            result.append(token.text());
        }
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

---

For all of these solutions, you should beware of infinite loops or stack-blowing recursion. What if you replace `"{foo}"` with `"{foo}"`? (or worse, what if you replace `"{foo}"` with `"{foo}{foo}"`!?).

Of course the simplest way is to be in control of the configuration, and simply not trigger that problem. Detecting the problem programatically is entirely possible, but complex enough that it would warrant another SO question if you want it.